# How to include read-only property in an OData query

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have the following models:

```
public class Employee
{
  public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

  public string Name { get; set; }

  [...]

  public int OfficeId { get; set; }      

  public string OfficeInfo
  {
    get { return Office.Info; }
  }

  public Office Office { get; set; }
}

public class Office
{
  public int OfficeId { get; set; }

  public string Info { get; set; }
}
```

I have a grid in the client side which rows I want to feed with instances of Employee, including the OfficeInfo in one of the columns, so I'm consuming it through the following query:

"/odata/Employees?$expand=Office&$select=EmployeeId,Name,OfficeInfo"

I have both entities registered in the IEdmModel:

```
private static IEdmModel GetEDMModel()
{
  ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

  builder.EntitySet<Employee>("Employees");
  builder.EntitySet<Office>("Offices");

  [...]
}
```

and my Get action looks like this:

```
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<Employees> Get()
{
   [...]
}
```

but I keep getting this Exception:

"Could not find a property named 'OfficeInfo' on type 'Xds.Entities.Employee'"

What am I missing here?

Comment: I know it doesn't answer your question, but is there anything stopping you from using `Employee.Office.Info` instead?

Answer (score 1):

You could mark the property `OfficeInfo` as required or add this property explicitly:

- Noting as required:

  ```
  builder
        .EntitySet<Employee>("Employees")
        .EntityType
        .Property(_ => _.OfficeInfo)
        .IsRequired();
  ```
- Adding explicitly:

  ```
  builder
        .EntitySet<Employee>("Employees")
        .EntityType
        .Property(_ => _.OfficeInfo)
        .AddedExplicitly = true;
  ```

Comment: After applying your solution, now I'm getting a different error:

System.NotSupportedException
The specified type member 'OfficeInfo' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: @slashCoder I assume, that the column `OfficeInfo` is used in the `Get` method in some Linq clause like  `employees.Where(_ => _.OfficeInfo == "?")` or `employees.OrderBy(_ => _.OfficeInfo)`. That is not allowed. Instead use the navigation property 'Office' like `employees.Where(_ => _.Office.Info == "?")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your model metadata and see whether following appears under 'Xds.Entities.Employee' type.

```
<Property Name="OfficeInfo" Type="Edm.String" />
```

Since it is a readonly property, you should turn on [isQueryCompositionMode](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/368278e40296e87a420f1bbffef038c3c4a852d2/OData/src/System.Web.OData/OData/Builder/ODataConventionModelBuilder.cs#L100) to get it shown in the model, like (can pass real HttpConfiguration there):

```
ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder(new System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration(), true);
```

After that, the query should work.

Note that flag is marked as for testing purpose, but it should be fine if you manually verify your metadata.